# Short if statement with or in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have if statement

```
if "1111111" in players or "0000000" in players or "blablabla" in players:
    do something
```

How to write in short ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if any(x in players for x in ("1111111", "0000000", "blablabla")):
    # do something
```

If you are going to be doing a lot of these membership checks you may consider making `players` into a `set` which doesn't need to potentially traverse the entire sequence on each check.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `any()`:

```
things = ["1111111", "0000000", "blablabla"]

if any(thing in players for thing in things):
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if any(a in players for a in list_of_tests):
   #something
   pass
```

If you are using `numpy.any()`, you will need to convert the generator to a list first.

```
if np.any([a in players for a in list_of_tests]):
   #something
   pass
```

Comment: @Blender thanks, wasn't sure when I wrote it if `any` played nice with generators.  I am used to using `numpy.any` which I am pretty sure does not.

Comment: I think `numpy.any` should work as well. All you're doing is iterating until the first `False`.

Comment: @Blender `np.any` (on 1.7) will return a generator if you pass it a generator.  It makes assumptions about the input being `array`-like.  Probably related to what you get if you do `np.array(t for t in src)` (which is an array with a single generator element).